# COPY from S3 to Redshift not recognizing newline

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run a COPY command from an S3 bucket to a Redshift PostgreSQL table, and I am getting the following error (in stl_load_errors):

```
err_code: 1207 

err_reason: Invalid digit, Value '2', Pos 3, Type: Short 

raw_field_value: 
2
2/28/15
```

The file has 2 lines:

2/28/15,Phone,Android,0,1,3,2,2

2/28/15,Phone,Android,0,4,1,2,2

The `CREATE TABLE` code is:

```
create table aggregate_table( date date, variable varchar(15),source varchar(15), prepaid smallint, direction smallint, total smallint, carrier smallint, carrier_group smallint)
```

It seems like the newline is not being recognized, and is trying to read the end of the first line and the beginning of the second line as one value.  I have tried using `delimiter ','` and `escape`, but nothing seems to work.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: Here's the COPY command (i've also tried it with `escape` at the end as well)

```
COPY aggregate_table FROM 's3://path_to_file.csv'  CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXX'  CSV delimiter ','  DATEFORMAT AS 'MM/DD/YY';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `DATEFORMAT AS 'MM/DD/YY'` to your COPY command. Otherwise redshift can not parse date in first column correctly, as it expects `YYYY-MM-DD`.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEFORMAT_and_TIMEFORMAT_strings.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks @quarterdome, but I'm getting the same error

Comment: I believe you need to add a CSV option too.

Comment: I've tried that as well, unfortunately got the same error

Comment: @zebrainatree, I just verified that it works for me end to end (create table, upload to s3, COPY). All using the exact commands you have above.

Answer (score 0):

@quarterdome thanks for working through this with me! After you pointed out that it worked, I tried from the beginning to end again. It turns out that when I saved the file without a .csv extension, it worked! –